# How to get ansible to respond to a password prompt

Tags: sudo, ansible, ros

I'm using ansible to script running a particular command ([rosdep](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep)) on a remote host. This command must be run as a regular user, not root, but occasionally prompts the user for their sudo password to gain root privileges for installing software.

Is there any way to instruct ansible to respond to those password prompts while running the remote command? I don't want to run the entire command with sudo, so the -K option doesn't work for this purpose.

Comment: Are you saying that during an install you get an interactive prompt for a password?

Comment: Correct. Some times when we run the command, it may prompt (multiple times) for the sudo password, other times it will not prompt (if root privileges are not needed).

Comment: `--ask-sudo-pass` doesn't work? (http://docs.ansible.com/intro_getting_started.html#remote-connection-information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider modifying your *sudoers* file so that those specific commands are allowed to run through `sudo` without such a password prompt.

The simplest but perhaps not the best way would be to use:

```
tessa    ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

which means all commands are allowed to be run through sudo without password prompt.

A better approach would be to figure out which specific commands require sudo permissions and then add them to the sudoers file.

For example:

```
tessa    ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/whoami
```

You can ship modified `/etc/sudoers` file/template as part of your Ansible playbook.

Comment: The one command I want to run must _not_ be run as sudo under normal usage. The command itself generates an interactive prompt for the sudo password under normal usage when sudo access is needed.  So I don't think that adding this command to the sudoers file will solve the problem.

Comment: Based on briefly looking at rosdes it seems like it generates a script to install whatever is necessary(example from http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/rosdep). Inside of that script certain commands are run through sudo(such as `sudo make install`. So if you are allowed to run that specific command without password prompt, everything should work properly.